# Problems with permissions in Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm developing an app, that uses some permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="aa.aa.aa.providers.imps.permission.READ_ONLY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="aa.aa.aa.providers.imps.permission.WRITE_ONLY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="aa.aa.aa.im.permission.IM_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="aa.aa.aa.app.im.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="aa.aa.aa.app.im.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="aa.aa.aa.app.im.permission.IM_SERVICE"
        android:description="@string/perm_desc"
        android:label="@string/perm_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="aa.aa.aa.app.providers.imps.permission.READ_ONLY"
        android:description="@string/ro_perm_desc"
        android:label="@string/ro_perm_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    <permission
        android:name="aa.aa.aa.app.providers.imps.permission.WRITE_ONLY"
        android:description="@string/wo_perm_desc"
        android:label="@string/wo_perm_label"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.MESSAGES"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

When I try to connect the app to the servers I need, from Android versions lower than 6.0.0 (not included), the app connects without problems.

But When I try to connect with devices from Android >= 6.0.0 the app never connects.

How can I fix it?

P.S:
Here is a screen on how permissions in Samsung S6 with 6.0.1 are shown:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: I think you need to user runtime permission for sms, please read  http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: there's no error. Just the app don't connect (is a chat app).